# Approaching a Summary w/ Detail Report PHP/MySQL Comparing Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Please forgive me if my question isn't exactly worded right, this is my first post. 
Also I'll say upfront I'm using procedural PHP and I do know the merits of OO PHP but just haven't yet learned that.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

Print a report in PHP with 4 levels of grouping (on category, subcategory, week and item)
without re-printing each group value more than once while showing detail (the date/vendor/price/qty of an item ordered) and then weekly item and subcategory totals. Here's roughly what it should look like: http://www.designtime.net/rpt.png

My approach:

I'm fetching from MySQL each occurrence of a given item in a given week so each row has the category, subcategory, week, item name, order date, vendor name, price, qty, ext., amt ordered and u/m. Each category/subcategory/week and item may repeat in the resultset so I need to filter the repeats out in PHP.

I don't calculate the weekly total or subcategory total in the MySQL query, I was leaving this for PHP (I don't see a way to do this anyway).

I store the MySQL results in a multidimensional array called ord_data.
Then I loop through this array twice- first to count how many occurrences each of category, subcategory, week and item and then I store these totals to a separate array called cnt_occurence so I know the totals upfront when printing the data so I can print the totals at the right place. I then loop through ord_data again to print out the data while comparing to cnt_occurences so I know when it's a) time to print a new category, subcategory, etc. b) time to calculate and print weekly item and subcategory totals.

Problem I'm having is comparing the 2 arrays. It's taking an awful lot of convoluted code to do this. Can you tell me:
1) Is my approach even sound??
2) Would you use a single array to put in all the group item I need the totals for (catid, totalcat, subcatid, etc...)

Here's an example of the code doing the counting:

```
    $cur_catid = "0";
    $prev_catid = "0";
    $num_cats = 0;
    $num_c_rows = 0;
    $cnt_occurences = array();
```

foreach ($ord_data as $o)
{

```
while(list($k, $v) = each ($o)) 
{

    if ($k == 'catid')
    {

        $cur_catid = $v; 

        if ($cur_catid != $prev_catid)
        {

            $num_cats++; // count distinct cats each item we switch

            if ($prev_catid != 0)
            {

                $cnt_occurences[] = array("catid" => $prev_catid,
                                                    "num_c_rows" => $num_c_rows);

            }
```

Comment: `I don't calculate the weekly total or subcategory total in the MySQL query` - this can be done in a much cleaner fashion in the mysql query.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Thanks, I started by using with ROLLUP modifier with GROUPING but the issue I had there was ending up with many extra rows that are making the data hard to read. (I'm actually needing to group on 7 different columns within the MySQL query for the data to come out right. So I get an extra row for all of those grouping levels and wasn't sure how to weed all that out.)

Comment: I suppose I could discard any rows having NULL for any of the 5 columns category, subcategory, week, item or order date. The only summary records I would keep are those having NULL for vendor.

Comment: If you're having to do extra grouping to format the data correctly, you can wrap those other 3 groupings in a subquery.  Without knowing your actual schema, that's as close of an answer as I can give you.

Comment: Thanks @SamDufel, I got this working using a combination of GROUP BY clause with ROLLUP modifier and some PHP logic to weed out the extra "junk" summary rows caused by those extra levels of grouping.